# Ack search with whitespaces

Tags: vim, ack, janus

I am using Ack with MacVim and the Janus plugin.
Everytime I want to search for a string in my project that contains whitespaces, I need to escape these with `\` or `.`

Is there a way to avoid this? I know that once you enter a whitespace, the directory that you search should follow...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

you can also quote your search:

```
:Ack "my searching query"
:Ack 'another one'
```